# Problem with defined integral when using an exponent

Tags: math-mode, fractions, integral

I used the following line to overleaf LATEX:

```
\[ 
u= u_0 +\frac{1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F_0(\frac {t}{t_0})^α \,dt 
\]
```

however the result was not what I expected  and the "dt" showed as an exponent together with "α". Do you know what might be wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you used that line verbatim, LaTeX will have trouble recognizing the α character. I'd recommend writing: \[ u= u_0 +\frac{1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F_0(\frac {t}{t_0})^\alpha dt \]

Comment: @JoshuaGonzález is correct about the alpha if you are using pdflatex.  However, if you use xelatex, it will recognize the alpha properly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton not by default

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I tested it before I posted the comment, using the setup that's used for TUGboat production, so it's up to date.  What am I missing?

Comment: @barbarabeeton by default xelatex math is same as pdflatex, preumably tugboat loads `unicode-math` if it detects xetex? By default you would get `Missing character: There is no α ("3B1) in font cmmi7!` from xelatex (if for example you use the document in my answer)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Didn't actually check that (we were on the way out the door).  Running from the command line, xelatex did run to completion, whereas pdftex blew up.  But you're undoubtedly right; xelatex assumed utf8 so it didn't hang.

Answer (score 5):

You should not ignore error messages (and also please post full documents that reproduce the problem, not fragments) After *any* error the pdf is not intended to be usable, just a possible debugging aid.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ 
u= u_0 +\frac{1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F_0(\frac {t}{t_0})^α \,dt 
\]

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.6 ...1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F_0(\frac {t}{t_0})^α
                                                   \,dt
?
```

and if you scroll past that,

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character α (U+03B1)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 ...1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F_0(\frac {t}{t_0})^α
                                                   \,dt
?
```

Any further errors (and pdf output) if you scroll past these errors are essentially spurious artifacts of tex trying to recover from the initial error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ 
u= u_0 +\frac{1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F_0(\frac {t}{t_0})^{\alpha} \,dt 
\]

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As @barbarabeeton has already noted in a comment, you should probably be using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, along with the `unicode-math` package, if you want to use a Unicode-encoded character such as `α` instead of `\alpha` in math mode.

You should probably also be thinking about enlarging the parentheses around the term  `\frac {t}{t_0}`, as is done in the second equation below.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[ 
u= u_0 +\frac{1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t} F_0(\frac {t}{t_0})^α \,dt 
\]
\[ 
u= u_0 +\frac{1}{m} \int_{t_0}^{t}\! F_0\Bigl( \frac{t}{t_0} \Bigr)^{\!α} \,dt 
\]
\end{document}
```